# ドコモの雑談対話APIのPython2プログラミングのPython3化

Tags: python, python3

はじめまして
最近Pythonを触るようになったのですが、ドコモの雑談対話APIを使って動かして見たいプログラミングがPython2のものだったので3に変換しているのですが、どうしてもエラーが出てしまうので質問させていただきました。
http://yu-write.blogspot.jp/2013/11/python-docomoapi.html
こちらのものをPython3で動かすために

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#Docomoの雑談対話APIを使ってチャットできるスクリプト


import sys
import urllib.request
import json
import os


APP_URL = 'https://api.apigw.smt.docomo.ne.jp/dialogue/v1/dialogue'


class DocomoChat(object):
#Docomoの雑談対話APIでチャット

    def __init__(self, api_key):
        api_key = os.environ.get('DOCOMO_DIALOGUE_API_KEY', api_key)
        super(DocomoChat, self).__init__()
        self.api_url = APP_URL + ('?APIKEY=%s'%api_key)
        self.context, self.mode = None, None

    def __send_message(self, input_message='', custom_dict=None):
        req_data = {'utt': input_message}
        if self.context:
            req_data['context'] = self.context
        if self.mode:
            req_data['mode'] = self.mode
        if custom_dict:
            req_data.update(custom_dict)
        request = urllib.request(self.api_url, json.dumps(req_data))
        request.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        try:
            response = urllib.urlopen(request)
        except Exception as e:
            print (e)
            sys.exit()
        return response

    def __process_response(self, response):
        resp_json = json.load(response)
        self.context = resp_json['context'].encode('utf-8')
        self.mode    = resp_json['mode'].encode('utf-8')
        return resp_json['utt'].encode('utf-8')

    def send_and_get(self, input_message):
        response = self.__send_message(input_message)
        received_message = self.__process_response(response)
        return received_message


    def set_name(self, name, yomi):
        response = self.__send_message(custom_dict={'nickname': name, 'nickname_y': yomi})
        received_message = self.__process_response(response)
        return received_message


def main():
    chat = DocomoChat('api_key')
    resp = chat.set_name('あなたのニックネーム', 'ニックネームのヨミガナ')
    print ('相手　 : %s'% resp)
    message = ''
    while message != 'バイバイ':
        message = raw_input('あなた : ')
        resp = chat.send_and_get(message)
        print ('相手　 : %s'%resp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

このように調べながら少しづつ変更していき、APIも.bash_profileに入れたものを使えるようにできないかと試しているのですが、現状では、

```
$ python talk.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "talk.py", line 71, in <module>
    main()
  File "talk.py", line 62, in main
    resp = chat.set_name('あなたのニックネーム', 'ニックネームのヨミガナ')
  File "talk.py", line 55, in set_name
    response = self.__send_message(custom_dict={'nickname': name, 'nickname_y': yomi})
  File "talk.py", line 33, in __send_message
    request = urllib.request(self.api_url, json.dumps(req_data))
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

このようにTypeErrorがでてしまいます。
このエラーについても調べて「モジュールの名前.対象のクラス」にしたら良いとは分かったのですが、どの部分に対してこの変更を行ったら良いのかもわからず行き詰ってしまいました。
また、そもそもPython2で動かしたら良いのではとも思い行って見たのですが、動きはしたのですが文字化けしてしまいました。

質問の書き方があっているかもわかりませんし、すごく初歩的なところを質問しているのかもしれませんがどうぞ宜しくお願いします。

Comment: 「プログラム」を書く行為を「プログラミング」と言います。

Comment: そうですね。日本語がおかしいですね・・・申し訳有りません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

この行

```
request = urllib.request(self.api_url, json.dumps(req_data))
```

は元々の [YuraYura](https://www.blogger.com/profile/15070671187447610013) さんによる[プログラム](http://yu-write.blogspot.jp/2013/11/python-docomoapi.html)では下のようになっていました。

```
request = urllib2.Request(self.api_url, json.dumps(req_data))
```

ここの書き換えが間違っています。[`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/urllib.request.html) までで1つのモジュール名です。このモジュールの `Request` メソッドを呼び出したいので、`urllib.request.Request` と書いてください。

---

参考: `urllib2` パッケージの[ドキュメント](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html)には以下のように書かれています。

> The [`urllib2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#module-urllib2) module has been split across several modules in Python 3 named `urllib.request` and `urllib.error`. The [2to3](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-2to3) tool will automatically adapt imports when converting your sources to Python 3.

Comment: 教えてくださりありがとうございます。教えていただいたように変更したあと、「module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlopen'
」と表記されるのですが調べてところ英語の質問にたどりつきどこかがPython2の表記のようなのですがどこが問題なのかわかりません・・・教えていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: コメントでQ&Aすると読みにくいので、別個の質問として投稿していただけませんか？　あるいは、参考情報の部分に書いた [2to3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html#to3-reference) というツールの出力を見つつドキュメントを調べるのも良いかもしれません。

Comment: そうですね、ありがとうございました。　少し頑張って見ます。