# ドコモAPIを使用した対話プログラムのエラー: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes

Tags: python, python3

[昨日質問させていただいた内容](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/37599/19110)は解決したのですが、その後

```
POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be of type str.
```

というエラーコードに悩んでいます。
調べたところスタックトレースを見ると良いともあったのですが、できるように色々いじって見たのですが、他にエラーが増えてしまうだけでした。

プログラムとして現状

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#Docomoの雑談対話APIを使ってチャットできるスクリプト

import sys
import urllib.request
import json
import os

APP_URL = 'https://api.apigw.smt.docomo.ne.jp/dialogue/v1/dialogue'

class DocomoChat(object):
    #Docomoの雑談対話APIでチャット

    def __init__(self, api_key):
        api_key = os.environ.get('DOCOMO_DIALOGUE_API_KEY', api_key)
        super(DocomoChat, self).__init__()
        self.api_url = APP_URL + ('?APIKEY=%s'%api_key)
        self.context, self.mode = None, None

    def __send_message(self, input_message='', custom_dict=None):
        req_data = {'utt': input_message}
        if self.context:
            req_data['context'] = self.context
        if self.mode:
            req_data['mode'] = self.mode
        if custom_dict:
            req_data.update(custom_dict)
        request = urllib.request.Request(self.api_url, json.dumps(req_data))
        request.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        try:
            response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
        except Exception as e:
            print (e)
            sys.exit()
        return response

    def __process_response(self, response):
        resp_json = json.load(response)
        self.context = resp_json['context'].encode('utf-8')
        self.mode    = resp_json['mode'].encode('utf-8')
        return resp_json['utt'].encode('utf-8')

    def send_and_get(self, input_message):
        response = self.__send_message(input_message)
        received_message = self.__process_response(response)
        return received_message


    def set_name(self, name, yomi):
        response = self.__send_message(custom_dict={'nickname': name, 'nickname_y': yomi})
        received_message = self.__process_response(response)
        return received_message


def main():
    chat = DocomoChat('api_key')
    resp = chat.set_name('あなたのニックネーム', 'ニックネームのヨミガナ')
    print (('相手　 : %s'% resp))
    message = ''
    while message != 'バイバイ':
        message = eval(input('あなた : '))
        resp = chat.send_and_get(message)
        print (('相手　 : %s'%resp))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

このような状態です。

質問ばかりの頼りきりで申し訳有りません。
宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`urllib.request.Request`](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request) の `data` 引数は bytes 型である必要があります。この引数に対して現状のコードでは [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) 関数の戻り値がそのまま渡されていますが、これは str 型です。今回は `Content-Type` が `application/json` なのでそのまま bytes 型に変換し

```
json.dumps(JSONを表すデータ).encode('何らかのエンコーディング')
```

という形で渡してあげれば良いです。 (補足：`Content-Type` が標準の `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` の場合、更に URL エンコードする必要があります。)

念の為、こちらで動作したコードを [gist に上げておきました](https://gist.github.com/nekketsuuu/e7b7a4f232af46a74306660c5c41a211)。

---

#### 参考

- [docomo 雑談対話 API のリファレンス](https://dev.smt.docomo.ne.jp/?p=docs.api.page&api_name=dialogue&p_name=api_1#tag01)
- [Python3: JSON POST Request WITHOUT requests library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25491541/5989200) -- Stack Overflow

#### 追記

他に気づいた点を簡単に書いておきます。

- Python 2 の `raw_input` 関数に対応する Python 3 の関数は `input` です。
- 一般に、任意の入力が考えられる場所で `eval` を使うのは危ないです。今回の場合、単に不要です。
- Python 2 と Python 3 では Unicode 文字列の扱いが変わったため、 `str.encode` 関数の挙動が変わっています。Python 2 では Unicode 文字列と単なる文字列が区別されていたため、文字列から文字列へ変換するために `encode` 関数が使われていました。Python 3 では文字列型の区別が無くなり、更に bytes 型が追加されたため、`encode` 関数は str 型から bytes 型への変換に使われるようになりました。簡単なサンプルコードを下に示しておきます。

  ```
  $ python2
  >>> u'あいう'
  u'\u3042\u3044\u3046'
  >>> u'あいう'.encode('utf-8')
  '\xe3\x81\x82\xe3\x81\x84\xe3\x81\x86'
  >>> type(u'あいう')
  <type 'unicode'>
  >>> type(u'あいう'.encode('utf-8'))
  <type 'str'>
  >>> exit()

  $ python3
  >>> u'あいう'    # Python 3 では u が不要です
  'あいう'
  >>> 'あいう'.encode('utf-8')
  b'\xe3\x81\x82\xe3\x81\x84\xe3\x81\x86'
  >>> type(u'あいう')
  <class 'str'>
  >>> type('あいう'.encode('utf-8'))
  <class 'bytes'>
  >>> exit()
  ```

Comment: すみません　渡したいデータをreq_dataやself.api_url・requestなど色々変えて、エンコーディングをutf-8にして、urllib.request.Requestの前に書いたのですが変化がなかったり、エラーが増えてしまいました・・・　どこが間違えているのでしょうか。

Comment: リンクした類似質問の[回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30760915/5989200)に引数の渡し方の最小サンプルコードがあるのですが、これを参考にして直せませんか？

Comment: 見させてはいただいたのですが、類似のものはどのデータを変換しているかなど大体何をしているのかわかるのですが、自分の触っているものに当てはめて考えようとしてもjson.dumpsを消してしまって良いのかなど、わからない部分が多く厳しいです。すみません・・・

Comment: すいません、私が勘違いしていました。雑談対話 API の Content-Type は application/json なんですね。回答を修正し、こちらで動作したコードへのリンクを付けました。

Comment: gitsまで使っていただきありがとうございます。元のプログラムと見比べてどこが変わっているかを確認し、動かして見たのですがTypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'と出てしまいました・・・調べたところ.decode('utf-8')を使えば良いとは分かったのですが、どの部分に対してこのことを言われているのかがわからず詰まってしまいました。nekketsuuu様の方では動いたとのことなので、私の環境のせいでしょうか・・・？

Comment: `__process_response` 関数で bytes 型の値を代入していたりしませんか？ ／
 念の為書いておきますと、こちらの環境は Python 3.6.0 (Anaconda) です。

Comment: わたしもAnacondaで3.6のはずなので同じですね・・・　__process_response 関数の代入されている値の確認方法などはあるのでしょうか？プログラムを見ているだけでは現時点でどのようになっているのかがよくわかりません・・・

Comment: `print(確認したい値)` や `print(type(確認したい値))` が使えると思います。

Comment: すみません。前に作っていたプログラムと干渉していたようで、仮想を別に作ったら動くようになりました。　色々聞いても快く教えてくださり、本当に感謝しています。ありがとうございました。